# Unable to set variable in a function calling it from another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, screen-scraping

I'm currently running a node js file and I'm receiving a post like so.

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var firstLine = req.body.firstLine;
    var secondLine = req.body.secondLine;
    var previewID = req.body.previewId;
    takeWebshot(firstLine)
    return res.end('<h1>Hello, Secure City World!</h1>');
});
```

when I console.log firstLine it's set to the req.body.firstLine let us say it's "Hello".  So firstLine = "Hello".
I then pass this variable to `takeWebshot(firstLine)`.
When I console log fLine in takeWebshot I can see "Hello".

```
    function takeWebshot(fLine) {
console.log(fLine);
        var options = {
          onLoadFinished: {
            fn: function() {
              document.getElementById("user_input").value=fLine;
              document.getElementById("second_user_input").value="AMAZON USERNAME";
              document.getElementById("preview_btn").click();
            }
          },
          takeShotOnCallback: true,
          captureSelector: '.fancybox-outer'
        };

        webshot('example.com/testy.html', './example.png', options, function(err) {
          if (err) return console.log(err);
          console.log('OK');
        });
      };
```

Here is my problem in this line:

```
document.getElementById("user_input").value=fLine;
```

fLine is not read anymore.  I tried passing fLine into the function here like so fn: function(fLine).  fLine now equals "success".  In my limited knowledge of JS it appears that the function fn: function() is a promise callback in the main node-module webshot.  The goal is I need

```
document.getElementById("user_input").value=fLine; to equal firstLine that is being sent by the other function.
```

EDIT: webshot is calling a phantom js to open a url headless.  I'm trying to pass the variable so it can fill out a form when it calls it to take a screen shot. That is why it has document.

Comment: where does `document` come from in a nodejs application?

Comment: webshot is calling a phantom js to open a url headless.  I'm trying to pass the variable so it can fill out a form when it calls it to take a screen shot.  I'll add it to the question. @Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `webshot` mentions that the script will get serialised before being passed to Phantom

> Note that the script will be serialized and then passed to Phantom as text, so all variable scope information will be lost. However, variables from the caller can be passed into the script as follows:

Cf https://www.npmjs.com/package/webshot#phantom-callbacks

So you should probably follow their instructions and have something like this:

```
onLoadFinished: {
  fn: function() {
    document.getElementById("user_input").value=this.fLineSnapshot;
    document.getElementById("second_user_input").value="AMAZON USERNAME";
    document.getElementById("preview_btn").click();
  },
  context: {
    fLineSnapshot: fLine
  }
},
```

Comment: @FabricioG I have updated my answer after looking at the documentation for `webshot`

Comment: Ah man!  Can’t believe I missed that!  THANK YOU!  @customcommander

Answer (score 0):

you cannot pass fLine into `fn: function(fLine)` since it is a callback function of onLoadFinished, the scope of the variable is not reachable inside, you can try `fn: () => {
document.getElementById("user_input").value=fLine;
}` this might work as fat arrow function with allow access to use variable outside function.

Comment: Am not sure the purpose of onLoadFinished method here, if you can elaborate I call suggest a better solution.

Comment: Yes onLoadFinished is in options which is used by webshot.  Webshot is a node module which takes a screen shot of a web page using phantom js.  So webshot uses "options" to get any details that phantom js will use.  In example document.getElementByID is filled out by value.  @Arulmozhi Manikandan

Comment: I understand now, you may try something like inside takeWebshot()  set the store fLine in local storge as `localStorage.setItem('fLine', fLine)` and inside onLoadFinished set the element value from local storage `localStorage.gettItem('fLine')`. I know this is like a patch for now, this will work, but I will run some test with actual setup tomorrow or later and will come up a right and clean solution.